# Changing content when user has logged in i.e. when session starts

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, authentication, codeigniter-2

How do I change the content for a user when he logs in? I mean like enabling voting, changing "login" to "logout" etc.
What I think to do is to start the session when user logs in (I am preferring to start session only when user logs in, not all the time). Then add data to the session's cookie like-

```
//controller 
$moredata = array(
    'username'  => $this->username,
    'login' => TRUE
);
 $this->session->set_userdata($modedata);
//redirect
```

Then in the other controller, where he has been redirected I check the following-

```
$login = $this->session->userdata('login');
     if ($login==TRUE)
```

Depending on the 'if' condition I will pass a variable to the view, with the help of that variable I will forward only the div/sections which should be shown to a logged-in user.
The problem is, while performing the above comparison Codeigniter shows following error (remember I haven't added 'session' in autoload array yet)

```
Message: Undefined property: NameOfController::$session
```

And If I set following in the autoload file

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
```

then the "if ($login==TRUE)" comparison always shows FALSE.
What should I do?

Comment: Sessions of CodeIgniter will start anyway since you are auto-loading them from config. Which of the two $this->session lines gives you the error message ?

Comment: if i dont autoload then "$login = $this->session->userdata('login');" line in controller gives "Message: Undefined property: NameOfController::$session" error. If I autoload then "if ($login==TRUE)" is always FALSE.

Comment: Now its more understandable. In your question you give the idea that even auto-loading the class you still get that error.

Comment: @mallix I mean Its not working either ways ie when I auto load session and when I dont autoload it.

Comment: What happens if you put `var_dump($this->session->all_userdata())` in your other controller?

Comment: @hohner ["user_data"]=> string(0) .. It was ought to contain 'username' and 'login'.

Comment: Well you're setting the cookie to `$modedata`, but the array is defined as `$moredata`. Is that just a typo?

Comment: @hohner Thanks a ton mate!. One more thing , would you say that the method I am applying to change the view for the user is fine/correct?

Comment: @longloop see my answer below for a potential solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you, I'd place all your session checks in a base controller which all your other main controllers extend. This allows you to [keep things DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself):

```
class BaseController extends CI_Controller {

   public function __construct()
   {
      parent::__construct();
   }

   public function isLoggedIn()
   {
      // Will return true or false
      return $this->session->userdata('login');
   }

}
```

And in one of your functional controllers (the example below handles users):

```
class UserController extends BaseController {

   public function __construct()
   {
      parent::__construct();
   }

   public function profile()
   {
      // Redirect if not logged in
      if (!$this->isLoggedIn()) {
         $this->redirect('some/other/page')
      }
   }

   public function register()
   {
      // Show different HTML if not logged in
      $data = array(
         'isLoggedIn' => $this->isLoggedIn()
      );
      $this->load->view('register', $data);
   }

}
```

The second method in UserController allows you to render different content in your view:

```
<? if ($isLoggedIn): ?>
   <p>You're logged in!</p>
<? else: ?>
   <p>Not logged in</p>
<? endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

On my last project we created a simple permissions helper that had functions to check for logged-in status and for privilege levels. Then we'd just call the helper's functions as needed from anywhere in the system. If the user is logged in and has privs for that content then they get the content - otherwise we'd redirect them to a registration or other error page. Since all of that logic is in the helper functions, we could wrap any permission-requiring code in a quick permissions call like `if(is_logged_in()){code requiring login to access}`.